# Cannot Update Date Fields in Excel Named Range with SQL Using ADODB from VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I am trying to run VBA-SQL to update existing entries in an excel table.  The data will move to a DB, but not until after rollout and testing for an internal application for a small group.  I have been able to update text (string) fields with the connection, but the date fields will not allow me to update. Only the Date Fields are a problem.  The Microsoft.ACE API is recognizing them as date format.

The code is as follows, with both methods and respective errors in the code,

```
Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset

DBFullName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
Cnct = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & DBFullName & "';" & _
  "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Macro;ReadOnly=0;HDR=Yes'"
Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.Open ConnectionString:=Cnct

‘ Method #1
 strSQL = “UPDATE StatusData SET [Last Update]=#2014-10-02 12:00:00# WHERE [Program Category]='Cat' AND [Program Name]='Prog' AND [LN] IS NULL AND [SN]='sn';”
Cn.Execute strSQL, RecordsAffected, adExecuteNoRecords
```

> Error “Cannot update ‘(expression)’; field not updateable.”

```
‘ Method #2
strSQL = “SELECT * FROM StatusData WHERE [Program Category]='Cat' AND [Program Name]='Prog' AND [LN] IS NULL AND [SN]='sn';”
Set RS = New Recordset
RS.Open strSQL, Cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
RS.MoveFirst
RS.Fields("Last Update").Value = a '"#10/2/2014 04:00:00 PM#"
```

> Error “Field Cannot Be Updated.”

```
RS.Update
RS.Close
Cn.Close
Set RS = Nothing
Set Cn = Nothing
```

Comment: Are you sure your database allows updates through this sort of connection?  You may need to attach with an account.  IE username and password.

Comment: Have you tried converting the date field to "General", then run your query and then change the format again to "Date"...?

Comment: I found a formula in an entry in the Field column.  Thanks all for your help.
The piece that works to populate Excel DATE is similar to `SET [Last Update]=#" & MakeSQLDate("10-2-2014 12:00:00") & "# "`

Comment: Edited the original description to remove my statement in error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method #1 worked once the cell with the formula was removed from the field.  Formulas are Read-only as well documented by Microsoft and other posts.